# Метка «родительный-или-винительный»

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Есть немало вопросов о том, какой падеж следует употребить: родительный или винительный. Например, последний вопрос: [Не упускайте возможностЬ или возможностИ?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/442971/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ac-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%98)

В связи с этим предлагаю добавить метку «родительный-или-винительный»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создать метку сами, просто введя ее название при редактировании вопроса.

Думаю, что предложенная метка действительно может оказаться полезной.

Comment: Создал и присвоил ее 18-ти вопросам.

Comment: @М_Г отлично, спасибо!